# How can i set unique ID in table? JS

Tags: javascript

This is the code that i have.(not mine from internet)
Now i want to add some option that when cell is created, i want to add some unique ID to each cell, and then when clicking on some cell i will be able to see that ID.
how can i do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Chess board</title>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .cell {
            height: 30px;
            width: 30px;
            border: 1.5px solid grey;
            border-style: inset;
        }

        .blackcell {
            background-color: black;
        }

        .whitecell {
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var center = document.createElement('center');
        var ChessTable = document.createElement('table');
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                    td.setAttribute('class', 'cell whitecell');
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                }

                else {
                    td.setAttribute('class', 'cell blackcell');
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                }
            }
            ChessTable.appendChild(tr);
        }
        center.appendChild(ChessTable);
        ChessTable.setAttribute('cellspacing', '0');
        ChessTable.setAttribute('width', '270px');
        document.body.appendChild(center);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Something like td.setAttribute('id', td_'+j);

Answer (score 2):

```js
var center = document.createElement('center');
var ChessTable = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.setAttribute('id','cell'+i+'_'+j)
        td.addEventListener('click',e=>console.log(e.target.id))
        if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
            td.setAttribute('class', 'cell whitecell');
            tr.appendChild(td);
        } else {
            td.setAttribute('class', 'cell blackcell');
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
    ChessTable.appendChild(tr);
}
center.appendChild(ChessTable);
ChessTable.setAttribute('cellspacing', '0');
ChessTable.setAttribute('width', '270px');
document.body.appendChild(center);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Chess board</title>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .cell {
            height: 30px;
            width: 30px;
            border: 1.5px solid grey;
            border-style: inset;
        }

        .blackcell {
            background-color: black;
        }

        .whitecell {
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is great but the problem is that i cannot get the real id. im using this let attribute = td.getAttribute('id');
                console.log(attribute) and alwys see 63 becuase this is the last id.

Comment: what do you mean with *real id*?

Comment: i mean that i have the board and now im clicking on some cell,, but when im looking in console log im not seee what the actuall id is, im seeing the number 63, and this is the last id that i entered. im using                     td.setAttribute('id',count) and count is from 0-63

Comment: I added this line `td.addEventListener('click',e=>console.log(e.target.id))` to my version to make it clickable

Comment: @MaROM you got a code that works in this answer, you can run it, so what is your problem? I don't get it. Are you trying to output `count` in the console instead of `target id`?

Comment: thats works great, what i needed thanks!